# why copy constructor is called at the time of calling overloaded assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

i am trying to understand the use of constructors and assignment operators. I am trying with this below program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass {
    int x;
public:
    myclass (int p) {
        cout << "calling constructor" << endl;
        x = p;
    }
    myclass () {
        cout << "calling constructor with no arguments" << endl;
        x = 0;
    }
    myclass (myclass &t) {
        cout << "calling copy constructor" << endl;
        x = t.x;
    }

    myclass operator=(myclass &t) {
        cout << "calling assignment operator" << endl;
        x = t.x;
        return *this;
    }

    void show () {
        cout << "val = " << x << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    myclass a1;
    a1.show();
    myclass a2 = a1;
    a2.show();
    myclass a3(a2);
    a3.show();
    myclass a4(200);
    a2 = a4;
    a2.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
calling constructor with no arguments // call 1
val = 0
calling copy constructor // call 2
val = 0
calling copy constructor // call 3
val = 0
calling constructor // call 4
calling assignment operator // call 5
calling copy constructor // call 6 i am not able to understand this print line
val = 200
```

call 1, is done from myclass a1;

call 2, is done from myclass a2 = a1;

call 3, is done from myclass a3(a2);

call 4, is done from myclass a4(200);

call 5, is done from a2 = a4;

but i am not able to get where call 6 is coming from, it is called  from the instruction:

```
a2 = a4;
```

But, how it will give call to copy constructor?

any help/pointer wil be a great help. I am diving into cpp from c, hence please bear with me.

Comment: You are overloading `=` as well.  It is coming from there.

Comment: yes, for that the print statement "calling assignment operator " is happening, which is the call 5. But why call 6? from where is got invoked?

Comment: The copy assignment operator should return a reference.

Comment: okay @sleeptightpupper, this might be the way i was not thinking. But it is returning this pointer, of the object which is already created. why copy constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 myclass operator=(myclass &t) {
    cout << "calling assignment operator" << endl;
    x = t.x;
    return *this;
}
```

The above function returns by value.
Returning by value is one of the cases when copy constructor is called.
Also AFAIK, this is not always true(returning by value calling copy constructor) as some compilers implement return value optimization.

Comment: yes. Thanks. i think this is the reason for the second call. i am returing values instead of reference. same also suggested by Slardar Zhang

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. I am not well versed with RVO.It would be great if you could throw some light on this.

Comment: @GauravSehgal For starters, `*this` and `t` are not the same thing.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: You can read up on RVO and the scenarios under which it may be performed. After you've done so, it should be clear why the result of this function and `*this` cannot be "optimised" to actually be the same object. RVO is only useful/valid when you're "optimising" away a local variable that was only going to die anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks.I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

(You copy constructor and assignment operators are slightly malformed: they ought to take a `const` reference as the argument, and the assignment operator ought to return a *reference* not a value).

With `myclass a2 = a1;`, `a2` doesn't yet exist. So the copy constructor is called to create `a2` using `a1`.

But with `a2 = a4`, `a2` already exists, so the assignment operator is used to *assign* `a2` to `a4`.

So the rule is essentially: If an object doesn't exist then it needs to be constructed. Your observed output can be explained by applying this rule.

Comment: thanks, but when i am saying a2 = a4; which should call only overloaded operator function, not copy constructor. but if you see the output call 5 is displaying the same. But from where call 6 is getting called? Please bear with me.

Comment: Your operator overloads are malformed. See my comment at the start of the answer.

Comment: yes, i cross verfied, return statement is the reason.

Comment: This answer includes the actual answer only in a parenthetical, which is odd. The rest is irrelevant / already known / already stated in the question.

Comment: The day my misuse of parentheses spills over from programming to prose is the day I should quit this dastardly field.

Comment: I think this answer does not answer the question. It's not clear to me, why the copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
myclass& operator=(myclass &t)
```

then:

```
calling constructor with no arguments
val = 0
calling copy constructor
val = 0
calling copy constructor
val = 0
calling constructor
calling assignment operator
val = 200
```

If you return by value, copy ctor will be called.
Return by reference to avoid calling copy ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment operator returns by *value*, so there's another copy made when it returns.

That's where the sixth call is coming from.

Typically, an assignment operator returns a *reference* instead, so that when you `return *this`, you really do return `*this`:

```
myclass& operator=(myclass &t) {
//     ^
```